# Как реинициализировать работу parallax в табах?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Добавил на сайт плагин parallax: [Ссылка на плагин](https://pixelcog.github.io/parallax.js/)

Использую я его в Tab'ах (вкладках) на странице. При смене вкладок картинка, которая используется в параллаксе, не меняется. Я так понимаю это происходит потому что изначально при загрузке страницы они инициализируются в блоках, которые по умолчанию `display: none`, а когда при смене табов блок становится активным `display: block`, ничего не происходит.

Вывод parallax картинки:

```
<div class="tabs__service-img-p" data-image-src="/html/img/service-img-1.png" data-parallax="scroll"></div>
```

Табы работают так:

```
var url = location.href.split('#')[1],
    el = $('.tabs-block-service .content .item[data-id="' + url + '"]');
if (el.length > 0 && el.closest('.tabs-block-service').length > 0) {
  var parent = el.closest('.tabs-block-service');
  parent.find('.item.--active').removeClass('--active');
  parent.find('.tabs .item[href="#' + url + '"]').addClass('--active');
  parent.find('.content .item[data-id="' + url + '"]').addClass('--active');
}

$('.tabs-block-service .tabs').on('click', '.item', function () {
  if (!$(this).hasClass('--active')) {
    var _parent = $(this).closest('.tabs-block-service'),
        id = $(this).attr('href').split('#')[1];
    _parent.find('.item.--active').removeClass('--active');
    _parent.find('.content .item[data-id="' + id + '"]').addClass('--active');
    $(this).addClass('--active');
  }
});
```

Я предполагаю, что если по нажатию на вкладки будет происходить повторная инициализация скрипта(как при обновлении страницы), будет всё ОК, но как это сделать, к сожалению, не могу сообразить.

Comment: Что значит как сделать? Как вы его изначально инициализируете, так и при переключении вкладки делайте

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение:

```
$(this).addClass('--active');
_parent.find('.content .item[data-id="' + id + '"]').parallax({imageSrc: картинку взять из фона блока, например});
```